# no idea what you want..I asking if patent #1894556 is worth anything

Tags: 1894556

patent #1894556 have been cleaning a favorite aunt's residence after her death. we found this tag off...is it worth anything? Thanks!

Comment: It’s not clear what you are asking for. Is it a device? What do you mean by “tag off”?

Answer (score 0):

A patent by that number expired in about 1950. Of course there are no longer any patent right remaining. If you have the original ribboned patent grant document it could have some (presumably small) value to collectors. If you have a patented cap remover from 1932 that might also have some value to collectors. Either would be off-topic here.
[image: image from google patents]